# VMFS 3 datastoes while Upgrading ESXi 5.5 to 6.0

Tags: vmware, vsphere, esxi

What happens while upgrading ESXi 5.5 to ESXi 6.0 to VMFS3 datastores? 
Since VMFS3 has deprecated in ESXi 6.0 .

Answer (score 0):

VMFS3 datastores will be preseerved during upgrade.

On datastatores TAB in vCenter or on ESXi host you can upgrade them from VMFS3  datastores to VMFS5 datastores.

Upgrade is non disruptive, it can be performed online with running VMs on them.

Please consider that there are some limitations regarding datastores upgraded from VMFS3 to VMFS5 so a better approach, if possible, would be to start with brand new VMFS5 datastores.

Refer to this KB for further infos:

https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2093576

Regards.